# Comparison Logic

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an `If` statement which I was assuming was comparing each value to each other. However it seems no matter what the values are (e.g. all values contain a count of 4) it goes to the else. Am I missing something in the `If` statement?

```
 If rst![CountOfProvider] = rst![CountOfDelivery Type] = rst![CountOfBU Creator] = rst![CountOfOrigin] = rst![CountOfSub-Destination] = rst![CountOfDestination Zipcode] = rst![CountOfCity] = rst![CountOfState] = rst![CountOfCost Zone] = rst![CountOfRate] = rst![CountOfMarket Name] Then
        chk = False
    Else
        chk = True
    End If
```

Comment: use `AND`: `If rst![CountOfProvider] = rst![CountOfDelivery Type] AND rst![CountOfProvider] = rst![CountOfBU Creator]..`

Comment: Isn't there a cleaner and simpler way? the way suggested i would need to test each one against every other one giving me a huge if statement.

Answer (score 2):

VBA doesn't perform that sequence of comparisons as you seem to expect.

Consider this simpler example from the Immediate window ...

```vb
Debug.Print 2 = 2
True
Debug.Print 2 = 2 = 2
False
```

I'm uncertain how VBA handles those multiple equality comparisons, but suspect it may be testing the first and then comparing the result from that with the next ... sort of like this ...

```vb
Debug.Print (2 = 2) = 2
False
```

The first comparison returns True, which is the integer -1 ...

```vb
Debug.Print CInt(2 = 2)
-1
```

So that means the final comparison would be equivalent to this ...

```vb
Debug.Print -1 = 2
```

And naturally that returns False.

Comment: So `4 = 4 = -1` is True ;-)

Comment: Yes, VBA thinks so.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The computationally quickest way is to hard code the comparisons. The more 
extensible way is to test via a loop.

HansUp makes a good comment - you should be wary of potential null values and add in a handler to deal with them as desired (e.g. using `Nz()` in Access or `IsNull()` in any host environment)

```
'Method 1
    If rst![CountOfProvider] = rst![CountOfDelivery Type] And _
       rst![CountOfProvider] = rst![CountOfBU Creator] And _
       ...etc...Then
        chk = False
    Else
        chk = True
    End If

'Method 2
    chk = True
    For Each ele In Array(rst![CountOfDelivery Type], rst![CountOfBU Creator],...your others...)
        If ele <> rst![CountOfProvider] Then
            chk = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ele
```

Comment: Wouldn't i also need multiple loops to check rst![CountOfDelivery Type] then with the other elements of the array?

Comment: @KSM why? Equality is equality. It is commutative so order doesn't matter, and if Count of Provider is equal to all of them then any other would also be equal to any other. For example `a = b and b = c` is no different (i.e. has the same truth table) to `a = b and a = c`. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: @KSM Be careful if your recordset fields can include Null because Null is never equal to another value and is never not equal to another value ... even when that other value is also Null.

Comment: @HansUp good point. I suppose the above would raise an error. Therefore it might be best to use the loop method as one can throw in a null handler more easily than in the long list of comparisons method.

Comment: If `ele` is Variant datatype in "Method 2", you might consider a comparison using `Nz()` like this to accommodate Nulls: `If Nz(ele, "Null") <> Nz(rst![CountOfProvider], "Null) Then`

Comment: It wouldn't cause a null error due to the fact its a query doing a count it will return zero.